# Quadratic Yield Response Function

Tags: quadratics

How do I find the quadratic yield response function in the form of "$Y = b_0 + b_1X+ b_2X^2$" for a set of data in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a two columns with your data points in each row, $X$ on the left.  Make an XY plot and Add Trendline.  One of the choices is polynomial fit, choose $2$.  If you right click on the trendline you get an option to show equation.

Comment: The follow up question is "Why may you want to assume that the response function is quadratic rather than linear?"

Comment: When you plot the data you may see there is curvature to it.  That comes out in the goodness of fit you are given.